# arangodb mac OSX not starting

Tags: macos, arangodb

I downloaded ArangoDB normal App and stored that as `/Users/myhome/dev_tools/arango-db/ArangoDB.app`. When I am launching `/Users/myhome/dev_tools/arango-db/ArangoDB.app/Contents/MacOS/ArangoDB/`, I am getting following error:

```
2016-10-13 21:14:28.089 ArangoDB[73100:18937114] CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/myhome/dev_tools/arango-db/ArangoDB.app/Contents/Resources/configurationModel.momd/configurationModel 2.omo'
```

However, I could see this file being present in mentioned location.

What am I doing wrong? Their web site does not show ample guidance to bootstrap this DB.

Comment: Did you install using brew?

Comment: I was trying through their DMG files; also, does brew installs the latest 3.1 RC1 version?

Comment: brew install --HEAD does. (Though remember that RC1 is not necessarily stable)

Comment: I tried with command `brew install arangodb --HEAD` but got errors saying 
`Error: An unexpected error occurred during the brew link step The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Directory not empty     usr/local/opt/arangodb Error: Directory not empty - /usr/local/opt/arangodb`